# Behaviour I cant explain

Tags: c++

The following actually compiles and runs;

```
template <typename T> 
class heap_ptr
{
public:
    heap_ptr(T* p) : t(p) {}
    heap_ptr(const heap_ptr&) = delete;
    template<typename ... U> heap_ptr( U ... u )
    {
        t = new T(u...);
    }
    T* operator -> () { return t; }
    // T& operator = (const T& o) { (*t)=o; return *t; }
    operator T () { return *t; }
    ~heap_ptr() { delete t; }
private:
    T* t;
};

struct A { int x,y; A(int x,int y):x(x),y(y){} };

void try_it()
{
    heap_ptr<A> woop {8,11};
    A a{5,3};
    woop = a; // <- here
}
```

However, the marked assignment puts garbage in woop. Why does it compile, and
why do I get garbage in woop? 
note: if I uncomment the assignment operator it works as expected, that's not the issue.

Comment: I'm going to guess putting your full heap_ptr class will be useful.

Comment: "if I uncomment the assignment operator it works as expected, that's not the issue". That's exactly the issue. Copy-assignment operator generated by default will copy the pointer, not the object behind it. And then the temporary object `heap_ptr(a)` is destroyed, deleting the data pointed to.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy write that in an answer, it's the answer.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: but the auto generated assignment operator don't take an A, only heap_ptr<A>

Comment: @sp2danny: Indeed; but this doesn't use the copy constructor. The assignment is equivalent to `woop = heap_ptr(a)`, which uses the variadic constructor to make a temporary, then the default assignment operator to (incorrectly) make both `heap_ptr` objects own the same raw pointer, to an object that's deleted by the temporary.

Comment: @sp2danny, yes. But you have the template constructor (not marked `explicit`) which the compiler uses to make a temporary object.

Comment: oh, the variadic accepts A&, because A does! Now I get it.

Comment: but A has an explicit contructor, does that not supress all auto generated constructors?

Comment: @sp2danny, no. The compiler will always generate a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator unless you do so yourself or suppress them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I uncomment the assignment operator it works as expected, that's
>   not the issue

That's exactly the issue. Copy-assignment operator generated by default will copy the pointer, not the object behind it. And then the temporary object heap_ptr(a) is destroyed, deleting the data pointed to.

Comment: This isn't really the whole answer. But we got to that in the comments :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that by not implementing your `operator=` you are relying on the default one which will copy the pointer of the temporary object and then destroy it, leaving you with an invalid pointer once the copy is finished.

This is an instance of the set of problems that derive by not following the rule of three (five in C++11). When you can, you should follow the [rule of zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/), though.

---

You are trying to reimplement a smart pointer. Just use `std::unique_ptr` and it **won't** compile, like you expect:

```
struct A { int x,y; A(int x,int y):x(x),y(y){} };

void try_it()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> woop{ new A(8, 11) };
    A a{5,3};
    woop = a;
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef7f3f8e85aaad2d)

Comment: primary reason this don't compile is `unique_ptr` has pointer semantics, not reference. And yes, I'm trying to reinvent the wheel, but with reference semantics.